# When should we use 'return this" and when "return new object" in pageobjects?

Tags: selenium, pageobjects

I'm reading: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects
In the example I read:

```java
public LoginPage typePassword(String password) {
    // This is the only place that "knows" how to enter a password
    driver.findElement(passwordLocator).sendKeys(password);

    // Return the current page object as this action doesn't navigate to a page represented by another PageObject
    return this;    
}

public LoginPage submitLoginExpectingFailure() {
    // This is the only place that submits the login form and expects the destination to be the login page due to login failure.
    driver.findElement(loginButtonLocator).submit();
    ...
    // Return a new page object representing the destination. Should the user ever be navigated to the home page after submiting a login with credentials 
    // expected to fail login, the script will fail when it attempts to instantiate the LoginPage PageObject.
    return new LoginPage(driver);   
}
```

Why does the method `submitLoginExpectingFailure()`  return `new LoginPage(driver)` instead of just returning `this`?
Both don't navigate to another page object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because When the credentials are incorrect it should again redirect to login page. So as per flow they are again creating `LoginPage`

There is no need to create a new Object for the Login Page.They are checking

```
 // Check that we're on the right page.
        if (!"Login".equals(driver.getTitle())) {
         // Alternatively, we could navigate to the login page, perhaps logging out first
            throw new IllegalStateException("This is not the login page");
        }
```

in the constructor.Instead they could have called an function to do so.It's a way of design not more than that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason that we expect that after `submitLoginExpectingFailure()` was performed we are still on the LoginPage and as we create new LoginPage object this check automatically performs in the class constructor here:

```
public class LoginPage {
private final WebDriver driver;

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;

    // Check that we're on the right page.
    if (!"Login".equals(driver.getTitle())) {
        // Alternatively, we could navigate to the login page, perhaps logging out first
        throw new IllegalStateException("This is not the login page");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is that in the code as presented, the constructor conducts a check that the browser is indeed on the login page. Therefore, as also pointed out by the other answers, the version re-creating the page object does a little more.

I typically put such a check in a *separate* method of my page object. This method then just checks that the browser is in the state as expected by the page object.
I typically invoke this method whenever some page interaction takes place and I want to verify that the browser is on a given page. I tend to *not* invoke this method in the constructor, as I sometimes find it convenient to be able to create a page object even if the browser is not yet in the corresponding state.

Another thing to consider is that this code base may be a bit incomplete. Typically, you'd have a short notification of the incorrect login. This might correspond to a new state (IncorrectLoginPage), which makes returning the corresponding new page object the natural thing to do for an incorrect login.

To answer your question in general:

- Use 'return this' if you're staying on the same page.
- Use a new page object if your browser should navigate to a new page (or state).
- Consider keeping your constructors simple and factor out state checks into separate methods.

I wrote a bit more about states and page objects, and separate 'self checks' on my [blog](http://avandeursen.com/2015/06/25/beyond-page-objects/) and corresponding ACM Queue paper [beyond page objects](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2793039).